# Multiple tinymce_hammer in same form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, textarea

Iam using tinymce_hammer as a rich text editor. But now i have a form where there are two textareas. they have to be tinymce_hammer. but now when i save, only one textarea is saved in the db. the other textarea value is not saved. please help me in this. Im working in rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tinymce_hammer load TinyMCE for you onto the page.  It does not rename the form elements.  I suspect you have form fields of the same name.  When two fields on the same page have the same name attribute then only the second one will be sent when the user submits the form.